# How come "roast" can mean a piece of meat that's been cooked in an oven and at the same time a cut of meat that is ready to be cooked by an oven?

Tags: word-meaning

[image]
Can I refer to any piece of meat I want to cook using an oven a "roast"? For example, Let's say I'm holding some pork in my hands and someone asks me what kind of cut of meat it is and what I will need it for. Can I just simply say, "It's a pork roast" even though it is raw and I haven't cooked it yet? Like the picture above, for instance. Does the whole meaning change if I remove the word roast from it?

Comment: You might need to ask a butcher or a cook.  Based on my experience, a cut of meat is called a "roast," if the only way, or one of the few ways, to cook it succesfully is to roast it. It is a generic term for many cuts of meat from different animals that are similar in how they are treated in the kitchen.

Comment: It's funny because I've never really thought anything of it, but today I was doing some food shopping at Walmart, and it got me thinking. I knew what it meant, but then I began wondering whether I could add the word "roast" to anything that is ready to be cooked by an oven, and then the more I thought, the more confused I got since I've never been to the supermarket to look for "Chicken breast roast." or "Sausage roast." sounds like it is used specifically for only certain cuts of meat and not everything else.

Comment: It's little stuff like this that still trips me up, even having lived in the US for 10 yrs.

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives, as a definition of 'roast' (as a noun): '1 : a piece of meat suitable for roasting'. The adjective 'suitable' covers the notion that only some cuts or joints will be called 'roasts' in a store. Once cooked by heating in an oven or over a fire, it is still a roast. Also dishes can be created for cooking in an oven and when they are served these can be 'roasts' too - sausage roast, (e.g. 'Southern Shrimp and Sausage Roast'). Here in the UK we have lots of vegetarians now, and a kind of loaf made of nuts, lentils, herbs, etc, is called a 'nut roast'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain cuts of pork, or beef, can be referred to as a roast.

With [beef](https://www.beefitswhatsfordinner.com/cuts/cut-charts)  you can have a cross rib chuck roast or a prime rib roast, etc. Similarly with [pork](https://opentextbc.ca/meatcutting/chapter/pork/) you can have various cuts called some kind of roast.  These refer to the location on the cow the cut came from, and the size and shape of the cut.

A roast cut is usually thicker, has a particular range of fat, and is intended to be cooked in an oven over a long time. If it has a bone, the arrangement is such that it is intended to be convenient to cut slices off the cooked roast.

So "roast" can refer to the cut of meat from raw to cooked, the process of cooking in an oven, and sliced portions of the meat in the finished dish.